# entity_print module -> file_unmanaged_save_data writes a pdf with 0 bytes

Tags: 9

We have a custom written module (not by me), that uses entity_print to create PDF documents. It was working fine until I upgraded drush from 9.0-beta4 to 9.5 (had to update drush commands). The functions all look like they are working the same as before, but the PDF written to the public:// directory is a file with 0 bytes. When I look at the /tmp/ files created in the process, they have the correct data written to them. Any ideas or hints as to how to debug this?

Comment: It will be near impossible for someone to help debug; we can only guess at what dependency relationship the custom module has with a particular version of Drush.

Comment: A little more info. It breaks at this method which is part of the contrib entity_print module: $this->prepareRenderer($entities, $print_engine, $use_default_css)